remove the first character of each .txt file with Powershell
I have 50 files in a folder that has to be loaded to SQL.
In most of the file(but not in all) the very first character is a hashtag that i would like to delete because it creates difficulty in the column mapping.
So I would not want to loop through all the lines of the file just delete the very first character in case it is a hashtag and save the file.
So i need to analyse also if the first character is a hashtag. If it is, then it should be deleted, if it is not, then i should simply exit from the file.
What is the fastest method for this?
I tried these:
$Path = "D:\folder\myfolder"
    $OldText = "#"
    $NewText = ""

--> this loops through all the file looking for hashtags
(Get-Content 'D:\folder\myfoldermyfile.txt' -raw) -replace '^.' | Set-Content 'D:\folder\myfoldermyfile.txt'

--> this removed the first character of each line, so its not good for me.


To complement Theo's helpful answer with an eye toward performance:
The only immediate problem with your code was the use of regex '^.', because the . metacharacter matches any character (except a newline, by default); therefore, using '^#' instead of '^.' fixes your problem by only matching files whose first character is # (and by not specifying a substitution operand to the -replace operator, the matched # is replaced with the empty string and therefore effectively removed).
Therefore, applied to all *.txt files in D:\folder\myfolder:
# Note:
# * '^#' instead of '^.'
# * -NoNewLine to prevent Set-Content from writing an extra newline.
# * CAVEATS: 
#   * UPDATES THE FILES IN-PLACE - to be safe, keep backup copies.
#   * The *character encoding may change*, because Set-Content applies
#     its default encoding, irrespective of the input encoding.
#     USE -Encoding AS NEEDED.
Get-ChildItem 'D:\folder\myfolder\*.txt' |
  ForEach-Object {
    ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) -replace '^#' | 
      Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName
  }

Performance-wise, there are two problems with the above:

Even though using -Raw with Get-Content is the most efficient way to read a file in full, as a single, multiline string (and analogously, so is writing the file content in full as a single string), you don't need to do that if all you want to do is to examine the first character.

By using the results of the -replace operation unconditionally, you end up rewriting even the files that don't need it, i.e. those that do not start with # (if -replace cannot find a match, it passes the input string through).


You can address these issues as follows, building on mclayton's suggestion to (initially) only read the first line of each file:
# Same CAVEATS as above apply.
Get-ChildItem 'D:\folder\myfolder\*.txt' |
  ForEach-Object {
    if (($_ | Get-Content -First 1) -match '^#') {
      ($_ | Get-Content -Raw).Substring(1) | 
        Set-Content -NoNewLine -LiteralPath $_.FullName
    }
  }

Note:

This optimization only makes sense if you expect a good portion of the input files not to need rewriting. If most of them do, the unoptimized solution may perform better.


Because your code uses the -raw switch on Get-Content, you will receive a single multiline string on which you perform the replace.
In your case, it would be easier to read each file in as string array and replace only the first line in that array.
Something like this:
$Path = 'D:\folder\myfolder'
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path)) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName  # read each file as array of lines
    $content[0] = $content[0] -replace '^#'      # remove the hash character in the first line only
    $content | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}

If you first want to test if the very first character is indeed a hash character you could do
$Path = 'D:\folder\myfolder'
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Path)) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName  # read each file as array of lines
    if ($content[0].StartsWith('#')){
        $content[0] = $content[0] -replace '^#'  # remove the hash character in the first line only
        $content | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
    }
}


If the file is huge, it might be faster to do something like $firstLine = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | select-object -First 1 and checking if the first line starts with a hash sign - you’d avoid reading the entire file if you can exit early…

@mclayton Yes, or use $firstLine = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -TotalCount 1

thanks a lot!!!!it's very helpful
